# How can I duplicate an array to another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, duplication

This seems fairly straightforward.

```
@new_email.distributions = @email.distributions.dup
```

After this is performed, both share identical distributions.

However, once the new object "saves". The old one loses all of its distributions.

Why is that?

**FYI:**

Distributions `belongs_to :email`. Email `has_many :distributions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The way you model this causes the problem!**

Each Distribution can only belong to just one email ... that `email_id` attribute is already set, and a Distribution can not belong to two emails! (there is only one `email_id` attribute in a Distribution).

**You should use a "many-to-many" or "has-many-through" relation** to model the association between your two models, and a join table between them, so you can store how distributions belong to more than just one email.

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't think of the obvious! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `clone`instead of `dup`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you using same object, try: `some_other_var = @email.distributions.dup` if I understood you correctly

Comment: It's a different object. `@email = Email.find(params[:id])
    @new_email = @email.clone
    @new_email.distributions = @email.distributions.dup`